# How to stream songs (mp3 files) faster in android app

Tags: java, android

I am using `MediaPlayer` class to stream MP3 files from server. `MediPlayer.setDataSource()` , `MediaPlayer.prepare()` and `MediaPlayer.start()` are the three methods which i am using to stream music in my app. The problem is its taking more than 20 to 23 seconds to start playing the song everytime. No matter what the mp3 file size on server its taking the same time to start. Do anyone know how to stream mp3 files more faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH) or HTTP Live Streaming(HLS) for rich and smoother streaming. Google has an advanced library called **exoplayer** for this purpose. Try `exoplayer` for the purpose.

- The library and demo is available [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)
- The docs are available [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)
- The developer guide is available [here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html)

Comment: I tried to use exoplayer but i am not able to include inside my project in android studio using  
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.1.1'  I am getting error Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.1.1
Install repository and sync project.
Don't know what to do now @Superman

Comment: I am unable to perform the seekTo() method in my app while streaming a MP3 file from the server.Everytime when i call seekTo(long MilliSeconds) it starts playing from the beginning. After doing a lot of search on this i found that my mp3 file misses the cues(Seek Index). How to add cues to my mp3 file? Please help. @OBX

Comment: Post a new question, and do not forget to add the relevant code you've done so far!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what code you have done may be old http request so use volley library
it is fast and many request can handle at a time.so use volley library .or post your code.

Comment: volley library can be used for StringRequest,JSONArrayRequest and JSONObjectRequest i guess. How to use Volley library to stream mp3 files?